# equivalent of 'python -c' for django environment?

Tags: django

Is there an equivalent of `python -c` when running in a django environment? I was hoping `manage.py shell` would support it but it doesn't. I want to be able to query a setting from the command line of a separate script (which is not running in a django environment). Something like:

```
python manage.py shell -c "from django.conf import settings; print settings.FOO"
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`manage.py shell` really just sets DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and PYTHONPATH properly, then launches a shell.  You can set those explicitly how you want them, then use `python -c`.